# Function never reached in Akka Streams Source mapping

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Given the following code:

```
class MigrationHandler @Inject()(database: Database, doUpdate: UpdateHandler)
                            (implicit @PropagateContext executor: ExecutionContext, actorSystem: ActorSystem)
extends Handler with Logging {
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
val buttonTypeId = "someId1"
val promotionButtonTypeId = "someId2"
val typeId3 = "someId3"
val typeId4 = "someId4"
val typeIds = Seq[String](buttonTypeId, promotionButtonTypeId, typeId3, typeId4)

def apply(requestHeaders: Headers): Seq[Future[Done]] = {
    for {
        typeId <- typeIds
        result = database.allByType(typeId)
            .map(contents => contents.map(content => migrate(content, typeId))
                .map(migratedContent => doUpdate(ContentId(migratedContent.id),
                    NewContent(migratedContent.raw, isDefaultContent = false), requestHeaders))
                .runForeach(_ => ())).flatten
    } yield result
}

def migrate(content: SomeContent, typeId: String): SomeContent = {
    logger.info(s"$content with type $typeId")
    content
}}
```

`Future[Source[SomeContent, _]]` is returned by the `database.allByType(typeId)`

In unit test where I am mocking `database.allByType(typeId)` to return `Source.single(SomeContent())`, I saw that I wasn't able reach the `migrate` function. Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure `database.allByType(typeId)` returns the expected value? Can you store it to `val` and then log the val or check it in debug?

Also, it looks like you return `Seq[Future[Unit]]` from `apply`, while `Done` is expected?

Comment: @amorfis yeaa, that was my silly mistake. In test case I forgot to get the futureValue from what was return by the class...